# Patterns for wrapping a command line tool in another language

Tags: design-patterns, command-line, word-wrap

I'm currently writing some Java to wrap around an extensive command line tool. It feels like I'm writing a lot of similar code.

I'm wondering if there are any established patterns for wrapping command line tools - passing arguments and handling output and so on.

Specific examples in Java would obviously be great, but any general suggestions or pointers are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) might be of some help to you. This is a little library aimed at simplyfying executing of external processes in Java.

There is also [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) for dealing with command line parsing if you need an extensive support for one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are primarily wrapping a command line tool, then you might want to consider using groovy instead of or in addition to Java. [Executing a command](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute()) in groovy is a simple as:

> def p = 'my command'.execute()
>
> print p.text //prints output

You could also chain these methods together like this:

> print 'my command'.execute().text